# Use one modal in another in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

hi i am new in zend framework. i have  created two modules names group and user. now i want the group dropdown in add user form so can you tell me how can i get this values ?
the below i have mentioed the file structure

```
module
    -user
       -config
       -src
         -User
            - Controller
            - Form
            - Model
       -view
         -user
           - user
             - index.phtml
             - add.phtml
             - edit.phtml
     -group
       -config
       -src
         -Group
            - Controller
            - Form
            - Model
       -view
          -user
           - user
             - index.phtml
             - add.phtml
             - edit.phtml
```

i want the group dropdown list in add user form
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are an example.

I create a Role service to retrieve all roles available

```
public function toBasicArray($aI_roles = null){

    if ( $aI_roles == null ){
        $aI_roles = $this->getRoles();
    }

    foreach ($aI_roles as $role ){
        $as_roles[$role->getId()] = $role->getName();
    }
    return $as_roles;
}

public function getAvailableUserRoles(){
    $aI_roles = $this->I_roleRepository->getAvailableUserRoles();
    return $this->toBasicArray($aI_roles);
}
```

Next I registred this service in Role Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig() {

    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Users\Service\RoleService' => 'Users\Service\RoleServiceFactory'
        ),
    );

}
```

Now I can call this service from everywhere in my application. For exaple in my User controller I have a select options named "role" to set user role.

```
public function __construct($I_userService, $I_roleService, $I_userForm) {
    $this->I_userService = $I_userService;
    $this->I_roleService = $I_roleService;
    $this->I_userForm = $I_userForm;
    $this->I_userForm->get('role')->setValueOptions($this->I_roleService->getAvailableUserRoles());
}
```

In User form I set select options simply to:

```
    $I_role = new Element\Select('role');
    $I_role->setLabel('Ruolo');
    $this->add($I_role);
```